# Trying to Port forward ssh and it stoped working today

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

I am trying to setup a ssh access to pi outside of my router and I bought a real IP from my ISP and it started working yesterday but today morning it suddenly stopped again.
Idk what else to provide please comment what else should I add, if need be.
I am using a Tp link archer AX1800 router.

Comment: It might be helpful to confirm that your external IP hasn't changed (since you said you bought a static one) and add any SSH/error messages you are receiving. You should probably also confirm that your settings in your router are still correct (i.e. SSH is being forwarded on the correct ports to the correct local IP).

Comment: Sorry to waste your time like this i just turned on a vpn on my pi which resulted in the ip being changed sorry... @Anaksunaman i wanna know will having a loadbalancer on top my smb server make it secure enough to send it out side on the internet?